# Basic (fake) raycasting on a 2D heightmap

Tags: c#, xna, raycasting, terrain, heightmap

I'm trying to shade a 2D heightmap using basic raycasting that checks if the ray is intercepted before it should shade it. However it's not working.

Map :
[image: Map]

And the raycasting is giving me this:

- Red is ray interception, but before intended position (so shading),
- blue is ray interception in the correct place (so highlights or just as-is), and
- yellow means no ray interaction before the while loop cut-out.

[image: Badx2]

The result should be red on back-facing slopes and areas behind large mountains (shadows) and blue on sun-facing slopes (highlights). There should not be any yellow. So this image indicates that either all rays are hitting the wrong place, or are intersected *always* somewhere else, which is impossible. I suspect the problem is with my trig.

`Ray` class:

```
class Ray
    {
        public Vector2 Position;
        public Vector2 Direction; // Think in XZ coordinates for these (they are on a perpendicular plane to the heightmap)
        // Angle is angle from horizon (I think), and height is height above zero (arbitrary)
        public float Angle, Height;
        private TerrainUnit[,] Terrainmap;
        private float U, V;

        public Ray(ref TerrainUnit[,] Terrainmap, float height, float angle)
        {
            this.Terrainmap = Terrainmap;
            this.Angle = angle;
            this.Height = this.V = height;
            
            // Create new straight vector
            this.Direction = new Vector2(0, 1);
            // Rotate it to the values determined by the angle
            this.Direction = Vector2.Transform(Direction, Matrix.CreateRotationX(Angle));
            //this.Direction = new Vector2((float)Math.Sin(angle), -(float)Math.Cos(angle));
            // Find the horizontal distance of the origin-destination triangle
            this.U = V / (float)Math.Tan(Angle);
            // Bleh just initialize the vector to something
            this.Position = new Vector2(U, V);
        }

        public void CastTo(int x, int y)
        {
            // Get the height of the target terrain unit
            float H = (float)Terrainmap[x, y].Height;
            // Find where the ray would have to be to intersect that terrain unit based on its angle and height
            Position = new Vector2(x - U, H + V);

            float Z = 1000 * (float)Terrainmap[0, y].Height;

            // As long as the ray is not below the terrain and not past the destination point
            while (Position.Y > Z && Position.X <= x)
            {
                // If the ray has passed into terrain bounds update Z every step
                if (Position.X > 0) Z = 1000 * (float)Terrainmap[(int)Position.X, y].Height;
                Position.X += Direction.X;
                Position.Y += Direction.Y;
            }

            Terrainmap[x, y].TypeColor = Color.Yellow;
            if ((int)Position.X == x) Terrainmap[x, y].TypeColor = Color.Blue;
            else Terrainmap[x, y].TypeColor = Color.Red;
        }
    }
```

Function that is casting each ray and how I am calling that:

`if (lighting) CastSunRays(1f, MathHelper.PiOver4);`

```
private void CastSunRays(float height, float angle)
{
    Ray ray = new Ray(ref Terrainmap, height, angle);

    for (int x = 0; x < Width; x++)
        for (int y = 0; y < Height; y++)
            ray.CastTo(x, y);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up using a much simpler approach with [Bresenham's Line Algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bresenham%27s_line_algorithm) to find the intercept point; I imagine it's much faster and more efficient than the way I was trying to do it would have been.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that when your `Direction` vector is applied to `Position`, it oversteps the lower limit (`Position.Y > -1`) before it has a chance to hit the surface (`Position.Y <= Terrainmap[(int)Position.X, y].Height`).

You could try to decrease the lower limit, or re-order your `if`/`while` tests.

Another problem might be that the `Direction` Vector is too large in comparison to your height-range. The distance between two neighboring pixels is 1, while the whole range of height differences is contained in the range (-1,1). This gives a *very* flat surface from the ray-casters point of view. When the `Direction` vector is applied to  the `Position` vector is takes a relatively small step over the length, and a relatively large step over the height.

Comment: Thanks for the tips; I rewrote the CastTo function with your ideas in mind, but it's still not working correctly. Although every pixel does get a ray interaction now, all the rays are apparently intersected before they reach their pixel (red). So I think it's a problem with my trig at this point.

Answer (score 0):

I also used [Bresenham's line algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bresenham%27s_line_algorithm) and decreased calculation time to 1/10! Example can be viewed at my GitHub project [TextureGenerator-Online](http://cpetry.github.io/TextureGenerator-Online/). The terrain tool uses this approach.

[image: Terrain tool]

See function `setTerrainShadow()` at [tex_terrain.js](http://cpetry.github.io/TextureGenerator-Online/javascript/tex_terrain.js).